# Visual Basic .NET. Jumping function to function by goto statement

Tags: vb.net, vba, goto

I am studying Visual Basic .NET and I have a question about about goto statement

I would like to jump function to function by click button.

For example , we have UI form and there is one button "stop" and there are two functions "first" and "second" .

I can be middle of running function "one" or "two"
When user click UI_BT_SAVE_RS button , just skipped one or two function and go to the end.

I would like to know that skipping two function when the users are clicking UI_BT_SAVE_RS button

For example,

In UI form we have button event and two function

```
    Private Sub UI_BT_SAVE_RS_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UI_BT_SAVE_RS.Click
// if user click this button then go to skipped: in the one_two()

End Sub

public sub one_two()
one() // just function name
two() // just function name
skipped:
end sub
```

when user clicks UI_BT_SAVE_RS button, i would like to skipped one and two function and go to end which is "skipped"

is there anyway that skip and goto some part of code by button clicking event ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `goto` or labels in your code, make whatever would be in the `skipped` label a separate function/sub that gets called by the `UI_BT_SAVE_RS_Click` event handler instead.

UPDATE:

For example, if you have 3 methods; `one()`, `two()` and `three()`, like this:

```
Private Function one() As String
    Return "one"
End Function

Private Function two() As String
    Return "two"
End Function

Private Function three() As String
    Return "three"
End Function
```

Now you want your button click event handler method to call `one()` and `three()`, then you just make a call to each function, like this:

```
Private Sub UI_BT_SAVE_RS_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UI_BT_SAVE_RS.Click
    Dim returnValue As String = one()
    Dim returnValue2 As String = three()
End Sub
```

Note: This gives the control to call whatever permutation of the `one()`, `two()` and `three()` logic you want.

Comment: Karl Anderson// thanks for answer my question. Is there any example or sample code ? I would like to know how to do it.  thanks

Comment: Well what would be in the `skipped` label in your example?

Comment: Karl Anderson// I mean, how can i skipping without using goto statement ?

Comment: Karl Anderson// thanks for answering my question. However, I would like to go to the end of program(finishing stage) when I click the button. For example, program can be passing function one, two, or three. However, when i click the button, program is stop running function and then skipping the all the function(one, two and, three) and going to the end.(but i should not close the form, so i can re-use it)

Comment: Are you talking about asynchronous operations, because the program as you described it will be synchronous (i.e. the program is waiting for the user to do something like click a button, but there is no background processing going on to interrupt/stop/cancel)?

Comment: Karl Anderson//i am not using threading. I am using doEvent to update the form. There is a little idle time to check the button clicking event. I just want to know how to finish running application on the UI thread without closing form( i mean skipping all the functions, and go to the end of the code by clicking button)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global var to check on each call to one() and two() or only one time for both. In one or two you can check for that var too so you can exit those if needed.

```
Public DoStuff as Boolean = True

Private Sub UI_BT_SAVE_RS_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UI_BT_SAVE_RS.Click
    DoStuff = False
End Sub

Public Sub one_two()
    If DoStuff = True then one() // just function name
    If DoStuff = True then two() // just function name
End Sub
```